# Enable Adhoc on Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, ad-hoc-networks

[Is] there any way to enable adhoc mode in JellyBean. WPA_supplicant hack isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

Root your phone, then use root explorer and [download this wpa_supplicant file](http://www.general-files.com/download/gs458407eahfi0/wpa_supplicant.html). Rename the original to wpa_supplicant_backup and set the permissions of the downloaded wpa_supplicant to match the permissions of the original one.

I tested on Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread it worked like a charm - almost. Sometimes I have to turn off the and turn on the WiFi twice but it's not a big deal.

Comment: pls search for the promisions because right now i can't find them to show you  how they look sorry

Comment: worked for ICS! No luck with Jelly Bean.

Comment: The link is dead.