# connect android devices in ad-hoc mode without needing to net connection?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, linux, ad-hoc-networks, wpa2

can we get android devices in ad-hoc mode using WIFI-card but without access internet ?
i mean to connect peers to send and receive messages between them but without having internet connection ?

i see this  [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32292/enable-adhoc-on-jelly-bean?rq=1)  talk about **wpa_supplicant.conf**  to enable ad-hoc mode, but it seems that there are problems in this thing.

and see this command `iwconfig` but this doesn't support on android !!

Answer (score 2):

Ad-hoc is not natively supported by Android. But starting with Android 4.0 (*Ice Cream Sandwich*), a new feature called [WiFi Direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) [was introduced](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html#UserFeatures):

> Wi-Fi Direct, previously known as Wi-Fi P2P, is a standard that allows Wi-Fi devices to connect to each other without the need for a wireless access point. This allows Wi-Fi Direct devices to directly transfer data between each other with greatly reduced setup.

<sup>(Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct))</sup>

> Support for Wi-Fi Direct lets users connect directly to nearby peer devices over Wi-Fi, for more reliable, higher-speed communication. No internet connection or tethering is needed. Through third-party apps, users can connect to compatible devices to take advantage of new features such as instant sharing of files, photos, or other media; streaming video or audio from another device; or connecting to compatible printers or other devices.

<sup>(Source: [Android.Com](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html#UserFeatures))</sup>

To me, this looks like what you are asking for: directly connecting two Android devices via WiFi without the need of a "mediator".

Answer (score 1):

While you can solve the ad-hoc wifi connection issue, I think your bigger problem is on the application level. All standard messaging applications do use some sort of a server to send the messages. Without the internet access you would have to set up your own server and at this point the ad-hoc wifi issue becomes a moot point - you will still need some infrastructure (the server) to be able to send the messages - why not the wifi access point then?

Comment: ok can i go low level to make this thing ?
can i enter the native code and linux to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

ad-hoc mode used to be supported in the Cyanogen ROMS, it is not in the stock images AFAIK.

Depending on your application, you might use Wifi Direct but I think it's a different API (rather than just behaving like an ethernet segment) and it does not cover all the uses cases that ad-hoc does.

Answer (score 0):

Wifi direct is not wifi in ad hoc mode.
Wifi Direct (p2p) is build over Soft Acces Point and make one of the device as "mediator" (call Group Owner).
I had the same issue for one of my dev.

Wifi Direct is very interesting for dev betwenn many device without acces point but it still a application client/server

Comment: Are you commenting on another answer or attempting to answer the original question?