# Connecting to Adhoc Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, ad-hoc-networks

I setup adhoc connection in Ubuntu Linux. How can we connect android devices (2.3.3 and 4.0) to the adhoc wifi internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: Android does not support Ad-Hoc networks by default (see also the [ad-hoc-networks tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ad-hoc-networks/info), which tells you this and more). This means, you will need to root your devices, and use an app for this specific task, which is known as [reverse-tether](/questions/tagged/reverse-tether).

Some solutions are summed up in the following questions (or rather in their answers):

- [How to share internet among 2 android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4117/16575)
- [Enable Adhoc on Jelly Bean](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/32292/)
- [Connect android phones through adhoc wifi network](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19129/16575)
- [How can I establish an AD-HOC Wi-Fi connection on my tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26896/16575)

As I did not use this method (had no need for it), I'm not sure what "easy solutions" really do. But if I remember correctly, OpenGarden's [WiFi Tethering](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=og.android.tether) supports this, as does [MANET Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.span).

Answer (score 0):

Yes ad hoc isn't supported in Android OS but typing 2 lines of DOS commands should solve the problem, I tested this and it works.

Type these 2 lines on DOS command prompt:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NAME key=PASSWORD 

netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I found it on [this blog](http://androiditnow.blogspot.com/2012/09/for-android-usersinternet-via-adhoc-is.html#.UXV0bUqlrGI).